# Why is JumpHeight of 7f not visibly lifting Player off ground?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm using this code for Jump but when Space is hit, the character looks like they don't move. I played with JumpHeight and it turns out the jump **does** work; it just takes like 50f for it to finally visibly jump.

My Player's scale is 1 (1 x, 1 y, 1 z) so it's weird to me that a `Jump Height` of `7f` isn't enough to make the character look like it's jumping at all. Is there something possibly deeper going on here?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpHeight = 7f;
    public bool isGrounded;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight);
                print("Space");
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            print("IsGround");
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            print("NoGround");
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Player just has a Rigidbody with XYZ Rotation Constraints, and a capsule collider with a bottom that is sitting slightly above the Mesh's feet.

Comment: What's the mass of the rigid body?

Comment: 1 Mass, 0 Drag, 0.05 Angular Drag, Use Gravity checked, Is Kinematic Unchecked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you name a variable "height" does not make it a measure of height.

The way you're using this variable, it is not a height but a force:

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight);
```

So instead of representing a 7 meter rise, it represents a 7 Newton nudge.

1 Newton is enough force to accelerate a 1 kg object by \$1 \frac m {s^2}\$. And you apply this force for just one frame, which might be something like one sixtieth of a second.

So if your object has a mass of one kilogram, then seven Newtons applied for one frame accelerates it to a speed of \$7 \frac m {s^2} \cdot \frac 1 {60} s = \frac 7 {60} \frac m s = 0.11666... \frac m s\$ upward.

In that same time, the default gravity of \$-9.8 \frac m {s^2}\$ would accelerate your object to a speed of \$\frac {-9.8} {60} \frac m s = -0.16333... \frac m s\$ downward. This is greater than your upward velocity, so you do not attain a positive launch velocity to ever leave the ground.

This is grade 9 physics, so it really should not be a surprise that 7 Newtons is not enough to lift your object.

If you want to parametrize your jump with a height, a good way to do that is to use `OnValidate` to transform that height parameter into the corresponding physics push you need to achieve that height.

We can use the formula for the height of a vertically-launched projectile at time \$t\$:

$$ h(t) = h_0 + v_0 t + \frac g 2 t^2$$

Setting the derivative to zero gets us a formula for the time until we reach the apex of the parabola:

$$h^\prime(t) = v_0 + g t\\
   0 = v_0 + g t^*\\
-gt^* = v_0\\
t^* = \frac {v_0} {-g}$$

And substituting that into our original equation lets us solve for the initial velocity we need \$v_0\$, assuming an initial height of 0:

$$h(t) = h_0 + v_0 t + \frac g 2 t^2\\
h(t^*) = 0 + v_0 t^* + \frac g 2 {t^*}^2\\
h(t^*) = v_0 \frac {v_0} {-g} + \frac g 2 \frac {v_0^2} {g^2}\\
2g h(t^*) = -2 v_0^2 + v_0^2 = -v_0^2\\
-2g h(t^*) = v_0^2\\
\sqrt{-2g h(t^*)} = v_0
$$

We'll take just the principal root since we know we're looking for an upward (positive) launch velocity.

Now we can write:

```
// Now this really truly does represent a height.
public float jumpHeight = 7f;

[SerializeField, HideInInspector]
private float _jumpVelocity;

void OnValidate() {
    // Compute the launch velocity needed to attain the requested height.
    _jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2f * Physics.gravity.y * jumpHeight);
}


void Update()
{
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
        // Apply an instantaneous impulse to reach our launch velocity from rest.
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * _jumpVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish my account was old enough to vote this up. Thank you.